# Java Hashmap - Multiple thread put

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

We've recently had a discussion at my work about whether we need to use ConcurrentHashMap or if we can simply use regular HashMap, in our multithreaded environment. The argument for HashMaps are two: it is faster then the ConcurrentHashMap, so we should use it if possible. And `ConcurrentModificationException` apparently only appears as you iterate over the Map as it is modified, so "if we only PUT and GET from the map, what is the problem with the regular HashMap?" was the arguments.

I thought that concurrent PUT actions or concurrent PUT and READ could lead to exceptions, so I put together a test to show this. The test is simple; create 10 threads, each which writes the same 1000 key-value pairs into the map again-and-again for 5 seconds, then print the resulting map.

The results were quite confusing actually:

```
Length:1299
Errors recorded: 0
```

I thought each key-value pair was unique in a HashMap, but looking through the map, I can find multiple Key-Value pairs that are identical. **I expected either some kind of exception or corrupted keys or values, but I did not expect this. How does this occur?**

Here's the code I used, for reference:

```
public class ConcurrentErrorTest
{
    static final long runtime = 5000;
    static final AtomicInteger errCount = new AtomicInteger();
    static final int count = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
        final Map<String, Integer> map = getMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Thread t = getThread(map);
            threads.add(t);
            t.start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            threads.get(i).join(runtime + 1000);
        }

        for (String s : map.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(s + " " + map.get(s));
        }
        System.out.println("Length:" + map.size());
        System.out.println("Errors recorded: " + errCount.get());
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> getMap()
    {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        return map;
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> getConcMap()
    {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        return map;
    }

    private static Thread getThread(final Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        return new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long now = start;
                while (now - start < runtime)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                            map.put("i=" + i, i);
                        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("P - Error occured: " + e.toString());
                        errCount.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test just showed you how `HashMap` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: You don't get exceptions if you use from multiple threads without proper synchronization. You get a broken data structure with no guarantee that the invariants still hold

Comment: Use `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: My recommendation: use `ConcurrentHashMap`, because you can afford a little performance hit over broken code because you *think* you understand concurrency. Then use the time you've saved to actually learn concurrency (the whole team!).

Comment: Yes, you get confusing results, because you are using HashMap in a way it not meant to be used

Comment: [Here's](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html) another cautionary tale about `HashMap` and naive assumptions about thread safety. It's fairly old and the implementation of the class has changed since, but the moral of the story is still relevant

Comment: Seriously, don't do this. Both the arguments for using a plain `HashMap` are invalid and you've got actual experimental proof that the whole thing doesn't work. What more do you need?

Comment: It is not that I don't know that this will break, it was a matter of "why does it brake like this?". @biziclop posted a link that was very helpful in explaining what is actually happening.

Comment: That's not "what is actually happening", it's "what can happen" (and it was a fun read). As said in the text, there's plenty of other ways it can break. The lesson to learn is: don't try to get clever with multithreading.

Comment: Well, I can see how the question might get miss interpreted slightly. I tried my best in formulated the question well, and I might have been somewhat off, but was I really that far off? I didn't expect these venomous comments.

Comment: Synchromization errors generally give undefined and unpredictable results. As you know, the docs say “If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.” This means, if you don’t obey this rule, you cannot know what happens. Specifically you cannot be sure whether any exception is thrown or not. So your test result is no surprise to me.

Comment: @Gikkman The comments aren't venomous. They address a common problem involving people assuming they understand concurrency, then making serious mistakes and hoping for some simple explanation/solution. I'm also pretty sure you're guilty of premature optimization, since I have a hard time believing a `ConcurrentHashMap` would become a bottleneck. Now that you've hopefully learned your lesson, you can try to find a book like Java Concurrency in Practice, so you won't make the same kind of mistake again (and can shine over your co-workers at work).

Comment: I disagree @Kayaman. Many comments are variants of "use this" or "learn this", but that is not a constructive comment, in my opinion. I consider them venomous, since I interpret that they add no content and downgrade they writer and the question. On this particular topic, I would say I have a relatively good idea of what's going on, but this case confused me, and I couldn't find a resource that explain it. Given that, do you think I shouldn't have asked this question?

Comment: @Gikkman I think most people react so strongly because most of us have made the same mistake at one point in our career, and still vividly remember the consequences.

Comment: @Gikkman No, I don't think you shouldn't have asked this question. There's no downvotes or close votes, so this is not a bad question. You say "I would say I have a relatively good idea of what's going on", but how do you know? It's easy to overestimate one's skills, especially considering a very complex subject like this one. Based on the wording in your question (reasons for `CME`, citing performance as a reason to prefer `HashMap`, and the expectation that `CME` would be the only problem in this case), I wouldn't say you have a *good enough* idea of what's going on (no offense).

Comment: I actually was never on the "use HashMap" side in this debate within the company, I merely included the prelude as an introduction as to why I came across this (might have been unnecessary in hind sight). Thing is, I was surprised that I was against it for the wrong reasons. I thought it would throw CME (and performance is something you have to sacrifice a bit if you want concurrency, so that argument is kinda moot imo), but the results my tests showed me something I didn't expect.

Comment: I guess the real lesson here is to remember that Undefined Behaviour is **undefined**. Be very afraid of UB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're faced with seems to be a [TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) class problem. (Yes, this kind of bug happens so often, it's got its own name. :))

When you insert an entry into a map, **at least** the following two things need to happen:

1. Check whether the key already exists.
2. If the check returned true, update the existing entry, if it didn't, add a new one.

If these two don't happen atomically (as they would in a correctly synchronized map implementation), then several threads can come to the conclusion that the key doesn't exist yet in step 1, but by the time they reach step 2, that isn't true any more. So multiple threads will happily insert an entry with the same key.

*Please note that this isn't the only problem that can happen, and depending on the implementation and your luck with visibility, you can get all kinds of different and unexpected failures.*

Comment: More pronounceably known as "check-then-act" bug. Often happens with lock-free code.

Comment: Thank you. This answer, as well as the [blog post you linked earlier](http://mailinator.blogspot.se/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html) helped a lot to get my head around this. I remember having read about this in school a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

In multi thread environment, you should always use [CuncurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), if you are going to perform any operation except get.

Most of the time you won't get an exception, but definitely get the corrupt data because of the thread local copy value.

Every thread has its own copy of the Map data when performing the put operation and when they check for key existence, multiple threads found it false and they enter the data.